# What are the downsides of using Kim's integral equation (1990) to determine the exercise boundary of an American option?

Tags: options, option-pricing, finance-mathematics, american-options, numerical-methods

I'm new to the industry and trying to wrap my head around American options pricing.

The integral equation<sup>(1)</sup> from Kim (1990) doesn't seem to make any strong assumptions, and approximating the integral with the trapezoidal rule and getting a piecewise exponential early exercise boundary seems like a solid approach to me.

**What are the downside of this, and why might you want to use other methods? What other methods are common?**

<sub>(1) See e.g. https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:510809/FULLTEXT01.pdf</sub>

**References**

I.J. Kim (1990). "The Analytic Valuation of American Options", *Review of Financial Studies* **3**, 547–572.

Comment: Have you looked at Ju: Pricing an American Option by Approximating Its Early Exercise Boundary as a Multipiece Exponential Function,The Review of Financial Studies,  ?ol. 11, No. 3 (Autumn, 1998). IIRC he starts with Kim's idea but takes it further.

Comment: @nbbo2 Do you know how popular the Ju method is? I always found it very elegant but see it rarely discussed. Are there more recent takes on the original method that further improve the pricing? As per Brian’s answer below, analytical approximations seem terribly out of fashion.

Comment: I don't know of any industry application of Ju's method nowadays. I studied it (and other approximate methods) in grad school years ago. Brian's comment seems credible to me.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: the most popular approximation in quant libraries I have known is not from Kim (1990) but rather the Whaley approximation.*

There are several good reasons to prefer numerical PDE solvers over Whaley or other approximations.  With the approximations:

- Deltas and other risk parameters are usually left as an exercise for the reader, but are crucial for professional options trading.
- Their errors are *biased*, and will be in the same direction for *all* options under certain market conditions, leading to lopsided positions
- They have no way to account for a term structure of volatility (mildly compensated in [Bjerksund and Stensland](https://openaccess.nhh.no/nhh-xmlui/handle/11250/163705))
- They cannot treat altered boundary conditions such as Bermudan exercise
- It is quite unclear that, even for a single option price computation, they save any floating point operations over a well-implemented PDE solver.  (The numerical PDE solver would be used *only* to estimate the early exercise premium, so it does not need the tiny grid spacings most people think it does)
- In the most common situation of wanting to price *multiple* option contracts, it is very easy to "stack" the contracts for a PDE solver. With some sorting tricks one can even get extra computational efficiency.  It is markedly more *difficult* to vectorize the approximations, leading to higher code complexity and, again, FLOP counts quite likely higher than the PDE solver.

Although almost every professional options pricing library I have seen *has* one of these approximations coded into it, I haven't seen any professionals *use* these approximations since 1995 (and that team quickly moved to trinomial trees by early 1996).

For these reasons, I consider the analytic approximations to be fun but irrelevant intellectual exercises for the academics and dabblers.